# How can I select the correct Int type at runtime

Tags: swift, generics, swift5

I am trying to determine the correct Int type to use at runtime.

Essentially, I am trying to do something like this:

```
func sizeToType<T>(size:UInt8) throws -> T.Type {
    switch size {
    case 1:
        return UInt8.self
    case 2:
        return UInt16.self
    case 4:
        return UInt32.self
    case 8:
        return UInt64.self
    default:
        throw MyError.runtimeError("Incorrect size")
}
```

But this won't compile, and force me to write it this way:

```
func UTILtoType<T : FixedWidthInteger>(size:UInt8) throws -> T.Type {
    switch size {
    case 1:
        return UInt8.self as! T.Type
    case 2:
        return UInt16.self as! T.Type
    case 4:
        return UInt32.self as! T.Type
    case 8:
        return UInt64.self as! T.Type
    default:
        throw MyError.runtimeError("Incorrect size")
}
```

But I am worried that the latter will actually not work as I expect. I don't want my UInt8 to be "upcasted" to an Int.

What's the right way to do this?

EDIT: to answer the question of what I am trying to accomplish. My end goal is to have a function that might look like this (I am trying to make this work, I know this does not compile as is):

```
static func parseInt<T : FixedWidthInteger> (unsafeRawPointer:UnsafeRawPointer, stride: Int, from:Int, length:Int) -> T {
        var res : UTILtoType(size:length) = 0
        for x in 0..<length {
            res += (unsafeRawPointer.advanced(by:(from + x) * stride).load(as:UTILtoType(size:length).self))
        }
        return res
    }
```

so that I can end up having the ability to simply call:

`let a = parseInt(unsafeRawPointer:pointer, stride:1, from:0, len:2)`

and this will create a `UInt16` and assign it to `a`, which will be of type `UInt16`. It seems redundant to me to specify both the length and `UInt16`, so I was hoping I could infer the type.

Comment: Neither of these functions are generic. They say they return a `T.Type` for any `T`, but really, only one value is ever possible. Swift is a statically typed language, even if you could make this work, how would you use it?

Comment: Hi @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I have edited my question to explain my use case. I don't know if this is doable in swift.

Comment: Hey, sorry I forgot to reply to this. I take that this is used in the network filter I saw you post about in other questions. What exactly are you trying to do with the output of such a function, if it were to exist?

Comment: Hey, no problem at all. I was trying to write functions that will parse N bytes from the packetBytes. I didn't want to manually write all the functions for each values of N. But I ended up doing it, as there does not seem to be a good way to do this.

Comment: What exactly does "parse" entail?

Comment: I mean, just retrieve N bytes from the unsafePointer representing the packet

Comment: The `unsafeRawPointer` already does that, so I'm not sure what you're asking about

Comment: be ispired https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067594/in-swift-how-does-one-assign-data-to-array-of-uint32/60103560#60103560